# How can i list the categories of a post type, the taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

How can i retrive the categories from a post_type that i select.

I have a Custom_field - categorie_serial

```
<?php

$values = get_field('categorie_serial');
if($values)
{
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($values as $value)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

// always good to see exactly what you are working with
var_dump($values);

?>
```

This code retrive me the categories but it retrive me an error
The line 40 is "foreach($values as $value)"

```
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/****/public_html/****/wp-content/themes/movies/tabserial/detali-serial.php on line 40

string(334) "Gen SerialeActiuneAnimatieAventura"
```

How can i retrive the only the parent categories?
I do not want to retrive Gen Seriale - categoriy , only Actiune..

---

RESOLVED:

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms('seriale','child_of=668');foreach ($terms as $term) {echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';}
?>
```

Comment: why are you saving categories as a string in a meta field?

Comment: hy milo please see up, i updated, i found a solution in wp codex, now how can i filter to display only the parent of a category?

Comment: Good that you found a solution. However, it's better to post it as an answer (you're allowed - and even encouraged - to answer you're own question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started

```
function my_cpt_cats() {
    $parent = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post', 
        'child_of'                 => $parent->term_id,
        'parent'                   => '',
        'orderby'                  => 'slug',
        'order'                    => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty'               => 1,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'exclude'                  => '',
        'include'                  => '',
        'number'                   => '',
        'taxonomy'                 => 'YOUR_TAXONOMY',
        'pad_counts'               => false 
    );
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
}
```

Remember to use your taxonomy name in the $args array.

Comment: sorry for the quck response , my solution did not work, after i added another post it in archive it apears duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The solution for other. Thanks to Milo.

668 - is the id of the category

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'seriale' );
foreach( $terms as $term ):
    if( 668 == $term->parent ){
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    }
endforeach;
```